# Amazon S3 Java Download Hangs on Last File

Tags: amazon-s3, download, progress, freeze

I'm having trouble with the Amazon S3 download hanging after the last file completes its download, "locking" the file from being deleted as it is "in use" still by the java app, otherwise they work fine.  Additionally, the progress doesn't appear to be updating correctly as the largest file simply says 100 once for its progress then proceeds to download without any further updates until it is completed, at which point it says "State: Completed" before the script hangs.  My code is below:

```
private static void getTheS3File(String bucketName, String file, String projID, String fileType) throws Exception {
    ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener() {
        int lastProg = 0;
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
            if (download == null) return;

            int curProg = (int)download.getProgress().getPercentTransfered();
            if(curProg != lastProg) {
                System.out.println(curProg);
                lastProg = curProg;
            }

            switch (progressEvent.getEventCode()) {
            case ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE:
                System.out.println("State: " + download.getState());
                break;
            case ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE:
                try {
                    AmazonClientException e = download.waitForException();
                    System.out.printf("Unable to download file from Amazon S3: " + e.getMessage(), "Error Downloading File", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    File newFile = null;
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, file).withProgressListener(progressListener);
    if(fileType == "img") {
        newFile = new File("/c:/test/" + projID + "/original.jpg");
    } else if(fileType == "txt") {
        newFile = new File("/c:/test/" + projID + "/test.txt");
    }
    download = tx.download(request,newFile);
    //System.out.println("progress: " + download.getProgress().getPercentTransfered() + " State: " + download.getState());
}
```

I pretty much hacked apart the sample code for the Amazon S3 Transfer Progress Sample that comes with the SDK to create a download version of the method without a GUI, so I'm surprised it even works.  I'm not that great with Java and even worse with the AWS API, so any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue of the hang.  Apparently **tx = new TransferManager(credentials);** should be **tx = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);**.  I'm not sure how the transfer manager works, but I'm assuming the reason it's hanging is that it's not closing the connection when it's done, but that's probably a whole other topic...

Comment: Did a little more digging and found that my original assumption of the transfer manager was pretty much correct, it does remain open until you shut it down via **tx.shutDownNow()** but this should only be called when everything is done as it will leave a partial file if shutDownNow() is called during a transfer.

Funny how I can't find the answer to something until AFTER I ask others about it...